# is it possible to have more than 2kword code in PIC16f877A?

Tags: pic

I Have problem with coding PIC16F877A. GOTO AND CALL can only manage 2kword addressing. in some compilers like MikroE liker is managed the code more than 2kword by adding PCLATH register but when I active interrupt everything messed up and result is randomly reset or my code execute wrongly!

Q: Is it possible to have more than 2kword code and also interrupt ???

When I cut my code and my code is below 2kword and all code is in PAGE0 with interrupt everything is ok. but more than one PAGE (more than 2kword) my code not working properly

Comment: What language? What is your development environment?

Comment: From context it seems that the OP is using assembly language. Should this be the case then the Interrupt Service Routine is not handling the PCLATH register correctly. The OP should edit the question to include a complete, builds without errors, code example that shows configuration word settings, reset and interrupt vector handling and the main application loop.

Comment: I use MicroBasic pro (MicroE) but you can see the assembly code in this IDE. I find new information. 2kword limitation is not the issue paging is the issue. you can have 1kword code but if the linker put it in 2 diffident pages we have same issue that is reseting and wrong OP location on interrupt. In MikroE you can use ORG comand to tell linker to put your code in which address of micro-controller. Still i can not find the solution. Thanks for participation.

Comment: Please add new information by editing the question, not by writing a comment. A code sample could be helpful. Also, please use all appropriate tags.